# Numerically compute a function that is almost 1

Tags: numerical

So my fellow numerical computational peeps it may be that I am suffering from sleep deprivation but I'm struggling to numerically compute a function x-> u(x) defined implicitly as follows:

```
 x^h(x) + x^-h(x) = a x
```

To be clear, that's just saying x raised to h(x) etc, and this should hold for all x. We can just consider x>0 and h(x)>0 actually.

Comment: May be a better question on [SciComp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) , [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) , or [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: Ah thanks for suggesting scicomp.

Comment: Is that h(x)? Otherwise where does x come in?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll leave the question here. The solution is to make the left hand side look like cosh(ax) and then we're done.